# Content outside collapsible portion of responsive Twitter Bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I'm trying to find a way to have some simple text content in a condensed view of a responsive bootstrap navbar, but nothing works so far. All I want is some simple [Username] [Log Off] at the top right of the navbar that, when the screen is too small or window is resized, doesn't get caught up with the rest of the links that are made into a list accessible by a button. I want the login info to stay to the right of that button and also be aligned to the right in full view (with the page links being aligned left).

Body:

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="~/Home/Index">Index</a>
          @Html.Partial("_TopMenuPartial")
          @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</body>
```

_TopMenuPartial:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

_LoginPartial:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
    }
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance. I'm very new to working with all this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the text and logout button *before* the collapsible menu. If you place it after the menu, it will be on a new line when collapsed.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
          Arnold Daniels
        </p>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly for me. Somehow, putting something aligned to the right before something aligned to the left in the code didn't quite make sense, but that's formatting for you...